# Figure out which employee has done more training

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have 2 tables, employees and classes_taken. I am trying to see which employees has taken more than 2 class. However, I am getting this error `ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE Position: 87`.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id integer primary key,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE classes_taken (
  employee integer,
  class text,
  foreign key (employee) references employees(id)
);

INSERT INTO employees (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'bob'), (2, 'sam'), (3, 'mike');

INSERT INTO classes_taken (employee, class) VALUES
(1, 'swimming'), (1, 'dancing'), (2, 'swimming'), (2, 'tennis'), (3, 'golf'), (3, 'dancing');
```

My select statement.

```
select e.id, e.name
FROM employees e 
JOIN classes_taken c
ON e.id = c.employee
WHERE count(c.class) > 2
GROUP BY c.class;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5296cb/4

Comment: aggregate functions should be filtered using "HAVING" clause.

Comment: What @Gouri said, plus your `group by` needs to be on `e.id, e.name`, not `c.class`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12a67/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the count filter in a HAVING clause, because it is on an aggregated value.

```
select e.id, e.name
FROM employees e 
INNER JOIN classes_taken c ON e.id = c.employee 
GROUP BY e.id, e.name
HAVING count(c.class) > 2
```

Comment: Note: Assuming `id` be the primary key of the `employees` table, you only would need `GROUP BY e.id` on Postgres.